# How to config options to remove first and last buttons of pagination in vue-tables-2

Tags: pagination, vuejs2, vue-component

[vue-tables-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2)

Install
`npm install vue-tables-2`

Require the script:
`import {ServerTable, ClientTable, Event} from 'vue-tables-2';`

So It's running on Vue admin theme, but not need to show first and last buttons on pagination,

`pagination.edge    Boolean Show 'First' and 'Last' buttons pagination: { edge: false }`

But never removed from pagination, have any answers, please... ::)

Comment: It's a useful stack, please follow you did this issue. thx ~

Comment: thanks for your confirmation, fixed with upgrade guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe It'll be doing well with this params configration. `pagination.edge`
[image]

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. let me try to do that. :)